# How to update href ID using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest-states

I have a following link in my code:

```
<li onclick="loadNewPage('test')"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
```

When the user click this link, I will use xmlHttpRequest to update some content in a DIV on the webpage.

But at the same time, when the user click the link, I want to add an id, so that the state of the button can be changed using CSS. (note the "id" being added to the link)

```
<li onclick="loadNewPage('test')"><a href="#" id="current">Link</a></li>
```

At the same time, if these is any other link on the page with the id "current" I want to remove that ID.

Is this possible?
How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice that every element that you want to handle in your HTML has its own, fixed ID.

I would suggest that your put an id when creating the page. If you want to change something, you may change the class of the element instead of the ID.

Initial:

```
<li onclick="loadNewPage('test')"><a href="#" id="section_1">Link</a></li>
```

After clicking:

```
<li onclick="loadNewPage('test')"><a href="#" id="section_1" class="selected">Link</a></li>
```

JQuery (amongst other libraries) provide useful methods to retrieve elements of a given class, in order to change them.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have

`<li onclick="loadNewPage(this,'test')"><a href="#">Link</a></li>`

and

```
function loadNewPage(theLi,sometext) {
  theLi.className=theLi.className==""?"clicked":"";
}
```